# integrationg a C# Winform with outlook 2010?

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I need to make a C# Win Form and attach it with outlook 2010. I want to work it from inside outlook by clicking a button. Please guide me how it is possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the documentation on how to create addins? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh128768.aspx

Comment: I even dont know is it possible or not. I have searched on google but no such example can be found. Is AddOn this like making a WinForm and attaching it ? Plz guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very generic question. To learn about Outlook Add-Ins with .NET in general, start from the "[Outlook and Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh128768.aspx)" section of the [Office Development Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/default).

Looking how to add a form to outlook is the wrong way to start anyway as forms are used for many things.

Start by reading the sections that concern the specific Outlook work you are trying to perform. If you want to customize the view of a message or a task, you should read how tasks or messages can be customized. If you want to add a new command, you should check how to customize the ribbon.